# How to sort Array of Objects by Object two values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects:

```
[{
 user: "userName1",
 roles: [7,4]
},
{
 user: "userName2",
 roles: [0,3]
},
{
 user: "userName4",
 roles: [7,2]
},
{
 user: "userName3",
 roles: [6,5]
}]
```

I need sort this array by `roles`. First `roles[0]` then `roles[1]`.

My result must be sorted like this:

```
0. userName1
1. userName4
2. userName3
3. userName2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{ user: "userName1", roles: [7,4] }, { user: "userName2", roles: [0,3] }, { user: "userName4", roles: [7,2] }, { user: "userName3", roles: [6,5] }];

data.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(a.roles[0] == b.roles[0]) return b.roles[1] - a.roles[1];
    return b.roles[0] - a.roles[0];
});


document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(data,0,2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you. Know you how I can sort all `roles` where value is `[0,0]` change sort by `username` ASC?

Comment: @DavidLences you're welcome, I'm happy to help you, you should learn more about the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.